# mysql where statement not displaying proper results

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a database that has 2 records in it:

```
id |  message  |    date     |   user    | option
---+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------
1  |  Welcome  |  2015-03-01 |           |   0
2  |  message  |  2015-03-05 |  admin    |   0
```

What I'm trying to do is if the user field is blank, it shows the message to all users, if there is a username (*such as admin in this example*) listed, it shows the one for that user, and a the blank message if it exist.

Right now it will show both messages if the user is `Pam` (*it should only show id 1*).

If the user is admin, it shows both messages.

It seems like its ignoring the `user = '$zuser'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 

  ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $zuser=$_COOKIE['aauser'];

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message WHERE (user = '$zuser' OR run_date >= CURDATE() AND user='')");

  while($quick = mysqli_fetch_array($result))           
  {
    echo $quick['message'];
    echo '<script>alert("'.$quick['message'].'");</script>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Run a var_dump on the cookie while making sure it's set/not empty. Also `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: there is also a difference between `null` and `'' (empty string)`

Comment: You can also try removing the brackets => `(user = '$zuser' OR run_date >= CURDATE() AND user='')` <= while doing what Ghost said.

Comment: There was nothing entered in user on one of them.

Comment: Entered... meaning what? Plus, where is the cookie initially set? Remember, cookies only get set AFTER the second page load.

Comment: changed it like you suggested `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message WHERE user = '$zuser' OR run_date >= CURDATE() AND user=null");
` now only displayes the message to the admin and not the blank user

Comment: the name is run_date or date? See your question

Comment: `if(isset($_COOKIE['aauser'])){...}` that will determine if it's set. Or `if(!empty($_COOKIE['aauser'])){...}`

Comment: Try `AND user !='admin'` then. Hard to say what your column's type is set at and if it does accept NULL or not. You can also try `IS NULL`.

Comment: @Ghost [Problem solved...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789718/mysql-where-statement-not-displaying-proper-results#comment45855082_28789803) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem @ Fred -ii- that was a bone head mistake i forgot that cookies were only set after the second page loaded!!!

Thank you for your help!

```
<?php 
        ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        echo $zuser=$_GET['usrname'];


    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message WHERE user = '$zuser' OR run_date >= CURDATE() AND user=''");

                while($quick = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

                {
                echo $quick['message'];
                echo '<script>alert("'.$quick['message'].'");</script>';
                }


        ?>
```

Comment: *[Blowing on fingers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789718/mysql-where-statement-not-displaying-proper-results#comment45854940_28789718)* ;-) you're welcome. *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message WHERE (user = '$zuser' OR run_date >= CURDATE() AND user='')");
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message WHERE user = '$zuser' OR ( run_date >= CURDATE() AND user='')");
```